# 401 - Unauthorized Error is coming in apple music api after generating the developer token

Tags: ios, node.js, apple-music, apple-musickit

I am trying to access API of Apple Music API

(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi).

After creating the JWT developer token, when i try to access the API, An error of `401 - Unauthorized` occurs.

I am doing it in the following way :

1. Registering a new music identifier (https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/devce5522674?sub=dev0416b9004)
2. Creating a MusicKit identifier and private key (https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/devce5522674) also downloading the private key file.
3. Getting the Kid (Key Id) and issuer (Team Id) .
4. Running the following code to generate the token :

````
const jwt     = require("jsonwebtoken");

const privateKey = fs.readFileSync("AuthKey_KEY_ID.p8").toString();
const teamId     = TEAM_ID_HERE;
const keyId      = KEY_ID_HERE;

const jwtToken = jwt.sign({}, privateKey, {
  algorithm: "ES256",
  expiresIn: "120d",
  issuer: teamId,
  header: {
    alg: "ES256",
    kid: keyId
  }
});

console.log(jwtToken);```

And after that checking the code using the curl command : 

```curl -v -H 'Authorization: Bearer [developer token]' "https://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/us/songs/203709340"```




I am not sure what i am missing here. is it something related to access or is it my code.
P.S : I am the Account Holder, so it is not an issue related to role.

Thanks
````

Comment: I've got this exact error! Did you solve this?

Comment: @Tometoyou no !  I am still searching. Please share if you find the solution.

Comment: @rajat_bt If you have solved this issue please share with us.

Comment: Have you found the solution?